# Have to import axios in any *.vue file of vue/cli 4.0.5 app

Tags: vuejs2

In my @vue/cli 4.0.5 app in any *.vue file I have to import axios, if I need to use it on this page, like:

```
<script>
    import {bus} from '../../../src/main'
    import appMixin from '@/appMixin'
    import axios from 'axios'
    ...
```

But I expected axios to be accessible in *.vue file of my app.
In src/main.js I have defined :

```
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import axios from 'axios'
...

Vue.use(axios)

moment.tz.setDefault(settingsTimeZone)
export const bus = new Vue()

axios.defaults.crossDomain = true
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.prototype.$http = axios
```

I have this question as priorly I worked in laravel 5 / vuejs 2.6 app I have axios was accessible in all *.vue files of my app
without any definition...
Why so and if I have to write

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

in any file where I need axios ?

**UPDATED BLOCK :**

```
In my src/main.js I tried and failed as :

...
import axios from 'axios'

export const bus = new Vue()

axios.defaults.crossDomain = true
// axios.withCredentials = true
// window.axios.defaults.baseURL =  window.App.baseurl;

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.prototype.$http = axios

const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
if (token) {
    Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
}

// home url in .env file
let apiUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
alert( '++apiUrl::'+apiUrl ) // CHECK IT VALID URL
new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    bus,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

Vue.use({
    install (Vue) {
        Vue.prototype.$api = axios.create({
            baseURL: apiUrl // !!!
        })
    }
})

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    bus.$emit('page_changed', from, to)
})
```

But next in my component I commented line with axios import:

```
<script>

    import {bus} from '../../main'
    // import axios from 'axios'

    import Vue from 'vue'
    ...
    export default {

        data: function () {
            return {
              ...
            }
        }, // data: function () {

        mounted() {
            this.loadTasksData()
        }, // mounted() {

        methods: {
            loadTasksData() {
                let apiUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
                let config = {
                    withCredentials: true,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    }
                }

                axios({url: apiUrl + '/tasks_paged/' + this.current_page, data: {}, method: 'get', config: config})
                    .then(response => {  // Error here!
```

I got error :

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: axios is not defined"
...
```

What is wrong? Did I put your construction in valid place?
Also could you please give more explanations (or provide a link) about this construction? It is about my expiarence ...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Vue.use({
    install (Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$api = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'PUT A BASE URL IF YOU WANT'
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks!. Please review UPDATED BLOCK